# Does Z3 support to encode array of Objects?

Tags: arrays, object, z3

I want to know does Z3 support to encode the array of arbitrary complex objects, such as a list or something.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Z3 supports recursive datatypes. We can use them to define lists, trees, etc. See section Datatypes in the [Z3 tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide). We can also define arrays using arbitrary index and value types. So, we can have arrays of arrays, array of lists, etc.
Here is an example. Also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/39LT).

```
(declare-const l (List Int))
(declare-const a (Array Int (List Int)))

(assert (= (select a 0) l))
(assert (not (= l nil)))
(check-sat)
```

Comment: Thanks.This is useful to me.